# Wicket human-readable URLs

Tags: java, html, url, wicket

Started learning Wicket after ASP.NET MVC and feel a little bit confused about managing its URLs. Here's the code:

**Application**:

```
package com.test.wicketapp1;

import org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication;

public class WicketApplication extends WebApplication {
    public WicketApplication() {
        mountPage("/page1", HomePage.class);
        mountPage("/page2", Page2.class);       
    }

    @Override public Class<HomePage> getHomePage() {
        return HomePage.class;
    }
}
```

**HomePage**:

```
package com.test.wicketapp1;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.BookmarkablePageLink;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;

public class HomePage extends WebPage {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) throws IOException {
        BookmarkablePageLink<Page2> bookmarkablePageLink = new BookmarkablePageLink<Page2>("gopage2link", Page2.class);
        add(bookmarkablePageLink);
    }
}
```

**HomePage markup**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <head>
        <title>Apache Wicket Quickstart</title> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" wicket:id="gopage2link">go page 2</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I wanted to have is pretty simple. I expected that there would be 2 urls: "/page1" for HomePage.class and "/page2" for Page2.class, then my HomePage has a link that navigates to Page2 and when HomePage is rendered, that link should have an URL of "/page2".

When I run the application and go to home page, it is rendered like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <head>
        <title>Apache Wicket Quickstart</title> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="./wicket/bookmarkable/com.test.wicketapp1.Page2" wicket:id="gopage2link">go page 2</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expected to have something like:

```
<a href="/page2" wicket:id="gopage2link">go page 2</a>
```

instead. What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is - I should use app's `init` method instead of ctor to define the mappings.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this. It might help

https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/request-mapping.html